# How to check that Request.QueryString has a specific value or not in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have an `error.aspx` page.  If a user comes to that page then it will fetch the error path in `page_load()` method URL using `Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]` and it works fine.

But if a user directly accesses that page the it will generate an exception because `aspxerrorpath` is not there.

How can I check that `aspxerrorpath` is there or not?

Comment: i also tried using Request.QueryString.Count != 0 but then the problem is if user attach any thing like ?abc=1223 then again it will give exception

Comment: `Request.QueryString.Count != 0` will simply tell you if there are _no_ parameters at all.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

You can just check for `null`:

```
if(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]!=null)
{
   //your code that depends on aspxerrorpath here
}
```

Comment: thanks it works i tried that previously but that time it not worked but now it's working..may be was missing something that time.:-)

Comment: @Peeyush You'll probably find you were trying to cast it to a '.ToString()' and therefore were trying to cast a null to a string value value before testing for the null value itself. It's a common mistake.

Comment: Note that this will fail to check if a key is present in the QueryString when it doesn't have a value.

Comment: In Mvc core it's request.Query.ContainsKey("aspxerrorpath")

Answer (score 42):

Check for the value of the parameter:

```
// .NET < 4.0
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]))
{
 // not there!
}

// .NET >= 4.0
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]))
{
 // not there!
}
```

If it does not exist, the value will be `null`, if it does exist, but has no value set it will be an empty string.

I believe the above will suit your needs better than just a test for `null`, as an empty string is just as bad for your specific situation.

Comment: And what if .NET == 4.0? Use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`?

Comment: if .NET == 4.0? Use IsNullOrWhiteSpace

Answer (score 19):

To check for an empty QueryString you should use `Request.QueryString.HasKeys` property.

To check if the key is present: `Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains()`

Then you can get ist's Value and do any other check you want, such as isNullOrEmpty, etc.

Comment: `Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains()` will actually return false when the key is present but has no value.

Comment: I think this is the best semmantically correct way to perform the check as Query.ContainsKey does not exist for some reason.

Answer (score 12):

You can also try:

```
if (!Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("aspxerrorpath"))
   return;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"]) //true -> there is no value
```

Will return if there is a value

Answer (score 6):

What about a more direct approach?

```
if (Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Contains("mykey")
```

Answer (score 3):

think the check you're looking for is this:

```
if(Request.QueryString["query"] != null)
```

It returns `null` because in that query string it has no value for that key.

Comment: Request.QueryString.GetValues(null).Contains("query")

Answer (score 2):

To resolve your problem, write the following line on your page's Page_Load method.

```
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"])) return;
```

.Net 4.0 provides more closer look to null, empty or whitespace strings, use it as shown in the following line:

```
if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"])) return;
```

This will not run your next statements (your business logics) if query string does not have aspxerrorpath.

Answer (score 0):

//Use Haskeys() And GetKey(0)

```
if (Request.QueryString.HasKeys() && Request.QueryString.GetKey(0) == "aspxerrorpath")
    {
        //It has a key and the key is valid
        string KeyValueByIndex = Request.QueryString[0];
        //OR
        string KeyValueByName = Request.QueryString["aspxerrorpath"];
    }
    else
    {
        //else...
    }
```

Comment: This code assumes there is only Key in the request.