# checking the querystring url in aspx code behind c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to check the return url that is in the url

I tried this

```
 if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == "//Default.aspx")
            {
                Label_Fail.Visible = true;
                Label_Fail.Text = "You have been signed out";
            }
            else
                Label_Fail.Visible = false;
```

But it is not working for some reason

Comment: What isn't working? Is that value perhaps url encoded before your comparison?

Comment: Hows your `url` look like?

Comment: How to test this in if   %2fDefault/aspx

Comment: http://localhost:55556/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fDefault.aspx

Comment: Once the logedout...I want to put some message in the label that ' he is signed out'

Comment: What happens when you add a breakpoint on the if statement then add a watch to Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]? Is the value //Default.aspx or /Default.aspx

Comment: Does Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].Contains("Default.aspx") works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mentioned in your comment, you have `%2fDefault.aspx` where `%2f` indicates the `/` if you decode it.

So you can try this

```
if(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == "/Default.aspx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if `ReturnUrl` is not blank rather than checking for a specific url:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"])){
    Label_Fail.Visible = true;
    Label_Fail.Text = "You have been signed out";
} else {
    Label_Fail.Visible = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this code maybe a simple contains works well

```
Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"].Contains("Default.aspx");
```

But, as you don't use the query string you can just see if it exists...

[How to check that Request.QueryString has a specific value or not in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678471/how-to-check-that-request-querystring-have-specific-value-or-not-in-asp-net)