# How to omit a querytstring value from link

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on an internal application and a new feature added was a way to seamlessly move through the development environments and keep the login session alive.

one flaw that I noticed is that each request is piling the same token to the url which after a few throws causes a bad request due to the length of the url body.

is there an easy way to omit the old session token from the url querystring?

thanks.

Comment: Sounds like a bug. Better to fix the bug than to try and mask it.

Comment: I would start by debugging the existing code.. pinpoint the issue, then refactor / fix your bug

Comment: the issue is we get the querystring then we add the auth code to the querystring, regardless if it already exists. how would I detect that? that is the question.

Comment: I did some poking around and found an answer to my problem

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8678471/how-to-check-that-request-querystring-has-a-specific-value-or-not-in-asp-net

Answer (score 0):

the QueryString namevalue collection is a read-only property on the Reqest object.

You'd be better served doing this with a cookie if all the sites are sub-domains such as dev.mysite.com / uat.mysite.com / qa.mysite.com. It gives you a lot more flexibility, separates the concerns, and allows you to check in a filter.

Comment: the issue is more that the auth parameter gets added more than once, so i just want a way to filter that value and either remove it or tell my app to not add another one.